# Quelle est cette chanson en français?

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire

Aidez-moi à identifier cette chanson française

[Мадемуазель Наталья, это ссылка специально для вас!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ABz144DwRY)

J'ai essayé de trouver cette chanson dans l'ordinateur! Mais malheureusement je ne parle pas français.

Des idées? Peut-être que quelqu'un comprend les mots? Je serais capable de rechercher cette chanson par le texte dans ce cas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Pour un flirt avec toi*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pour_un_flirt) by Michel Delpech - 1971, a major hit in France.